# Field 'id' expected a number but got '-'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I'm basically new to the Django and got such ValueError.
I have a basic user model inheriting from AbstractUser class.
Also I have Profile model (in separate app), which also contain OneToOneField refering to my User model.

First of all, lets take a look on my **Profile model**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='-')

full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='-')
about = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="User don't set any information about")

register_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/no_avatar.png')

active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

website = models.URLField(default='-')
github = models.URLField(default='-')
twitter = models.URLField(default='-')
instagram = models.URLField(default='-')
facebook = models.URLField(default='-')
```

Secondly when I create a new User I have to also create his own profile (model instance refering to the user instance).
Let's look on my view.py where I creating a new user.

```
class SignupView(View):
def get(self, request):
    """
    :param request:
    :return: Register page
    """
    return render(request, "login/register.html", {
        'form': SignupForm()
    })

def post(self, request):
    """
    Tests data validity,creating user if everything is ok.
    :param request:
    :return: Particular user page if data is valid, otherwise it will return couple of mistake messages
    """

    form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password1 = form.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password1 == password2:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password1)
                profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
                user.save()
                profile.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myprofile:index', args=(user.id, )))
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'login/register.html', {
                    'message': 'Username is already taken',
                    'form': form
                })
        else:
            return render(request, 'login/register.html', {
                'message': 'Passwords must match',
                'form': form
            })
    return render(request, 'login/register.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

I left the whole class based view but you likely need to check post function out.
And this is where the problem begins.
I getting an error on **"profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)"** line. On this moment Django stopping an execution and raising an **ValueError** with **"Field 'id' expected a number but got '-'.
"**.
What I already have tried?
Remove a database and also remove migrations by **"python3 manage.py migrate app zero --fake"** and then reapplying migrations to a new database.
So I don't probably think this is a problem with migration (not sure).
But what did I miss?
I will be very grateful  for any help.

Comment: You need to use a number for the default. Check the country foreign key again.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me, problem solved